# Pattern pipeline performance implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, pipeline, tpl-dataflow

I'm looking for advice on how to develop a multi-tasking pipeline over the C# language
Namely:

1. a first task used to acquire images continuously
2. make each image available to one or more processing tasks.
3. a task to display the results.

The tasks are perpetual, but the pipeline can be stopped at any time and restarted.

In terms of performance, you would be moving towards what type of development (technology) :

- List + BlockingCollection
- Task[] = new Task(action, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Start() + BlockingCollection for information sharing.
- Async task ? for a perpetual task
- Or use DataFlow technology.

[Edit]
Stop use case: need to stop acquisition -> the acquisition task must be stopped. The other tasks can also be stopped or wait for a new image to be captured.

The first task is an image producer and the others are consumers.
What type of processing is involved? It may involve monitoring and then displaying a visual notification by means of an alert.

Comment: What will the tasks to when the pipeline is stopped? Will the first task continue to acquire images? What will the first task do with those images? Will the processing tasks continue to process their latest image, or will they suspend due to lack of data to process? What results will be displayed when the data flow is interrupted?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how to implement the design model.
It's not really asynchronous, because the tasks have been running for a long time.

Comment: What you describe is a distributed synchronous architecture. Using a classic Unix pipe, which provides a one-to-one relationship between producer and consumer, the producer is suspended when the pipe is full and the consumer is suspended when the pipe is empty. You might consider a similar behavior in your architecture.

Comment: You can provide separate queues for each consumer. In this model you will attempt to write to the first queue. If it is full then attempt to write to the second queue. Continue attempting queues, treating the list of queues as a circular buffer, until the write succeeds. You can stop a pipeline by marking its queue as full and empty at the same time.